# Conditional HTML attribute in JSPX

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, jspx

What's the right way to print an html attribute conditionally using JSPX?

These both throw validation errors on p tag:

```
    /* first try */

<p ${true ? 'name="foobar"' : ''}>hello</p>

    /* second one */

<c:set var="somevar" scope="page">
  <c:if test="${true}">
    name="foobar"
  </c:if>
</c:set>
<p ${somevar}>hello</p>
```

Element type "p" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:41)

**EDIT: appended full code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<div xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" xmlns:field="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/form/fields" xmlns:form="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/form" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags" version="2.0">
    <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
    <jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <p ${true ? 'name="foobar"' : ''}>hello</p>

</div>
```

Comment: I've just tried your original `<p ${true ? 'name="foobar"' : ''}>hello</p>` on Tomcat 6.0.26 and it worked, so something else is wrong with your code / server.

Comment: I just tried the same: <p ${true ? 'name="true"' : 'name="false"'}>hello</p> and it works OK in Tomcat 7

Comment: but I don't think that's a valid reason for down-voting: someone else will come across this in the future and maybe find it to be useful.

Comment: The problem is that Jasper JSP compiler tries to validate XML before it processes EL. I couldn't find any way to disable XML validation.

Comment: indeed the code doesn't work with validation enabled. i'm looking for a way to have it disabled.

Comment: @damo_inc: I guess this will work in a plain jsp, but not in a jspx, since it uses xml syntax. Which one did you try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that Jasper tries to validate well-formness of JSP before processing EL.

This happens because JSPX extension that your file supposedly has means that it is a JSP Document. And [JavaServer Pages Specification](http://jsp.java.net/spec/jsp-2_1-fr-spec.pdf) says:

> It is a translation-time error for a file that is identified as a JSP
>   document to not be a well-formed, namespace-aware, XML document.

I couldn't find any way to instruct Jasper to disable XML well-formness validation.

The Ant task to pre-compile JSP files as described in [Tomcat docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jasper-howto.html#Web_Application_Compilation) has got `validateXml` parameter. But it just skips checks for a [valid XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Schemas_and_validation), not for [well-formed XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_document).

So your options are either to rename your file to JSP, or add `<is-xml>false</is-xml>` to `web.xml`, or to follow @damo_inc's suggestion.

Comment: is-xml is true by default when using jspx -> http://onjava.com/onjava/2004/04/21/JSP2part3.html this states that inside jspx is impossible to use such a costruct

Comment: if i turn off jsp document support by either changing extension to .jsp or using is-xml=false i cannot run jsp tags anymore (ie. it throws error about using jsp:output and so on). so i guess the final answer is that is impossible to conditionally print an attribute inside jspx. that's what we get for free after 10 years of j2ee specs.

Answer (score 1):

A bit simplistic maybe, but should work:

```
      <c:if test="${true}">
        <p name="foobar">hello</p>
      </c:if>
      <c:if test="!${true}">
        <p>Hello</p>
      </c:if>
```

EDIT:

tested this:

```
<p ${true ? 'name="true"' : 'name="false"'}>hello</p>
```

...and it works fine. Something must be wrong with your page.

EDIT 2:

this works OK:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<div xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" >
    <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
    <jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <p ${true ? 'name="foobar"' : ''}>hello</p>

</div>
```

Something wrong with some of the xmnls attributes.

Comment: that's ok but in this way if i have 10 conditional attributes i have to write 10! possible switches =)

Comment: this works inside jsp but not inside jspx (ie. with xml validation)

Answer (score 0):

I did find a way to do it.

I know it has been a looong time since this was asked but thought someone could benefit from my finding.

I guess it **is** a complete hack, but it works.

Look at this:

```
&lt;div id="something1" <c:if test="true">class="hide"</c:if>&gt;
    something2
&lt;/div&gt;
```

With the `&lt;` and `&gt;` the tag is not validated.

The browser's source code shows:

```
<div id="something1" class="hide">
    something2
</div>
```

Got the idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12110882/2796922).

Hope someone find it usefull