# Get escaping error when putting JSTL variable into Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, jstl

I follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287114/how-to-set-the-jstl-variable-value-in-javascript) post to render a javascript variable using JSTL variable:

```
var size= "<c:out value='${fn:length(orders)}'/>";
```

However, not quite lucky, I get an exception like this:

```
Element type "size" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
```

So I use

```
var size= &lt;c:out value='${fn:length(orders)}'/&gt;;
```

instead, but no luck. After add double quote:

```
var size= "&lt;c:out value='${fn:length(orders)}'/&gt;";
```

Still not working..So how to escaping and make it work?

### UPDATE 1

The jspx is looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<jsp:root 
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:field="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/form/fields" 
    xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" 
    xmlns:page="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/form" 
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags" 
    xmlns:form="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" 
    xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" 
    xmlns:fmt="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"
    version="2.1">
<div>
<jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
<jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<page:show>
   <form:form.....
    <!--body of the form -->
   </form:form>
</page:show>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //jquery and so...
    ....
    var size= "<c:out value='${fn:length(orders)}'/>";
    ....
</script>

</div>
</jsp:root>
```

Comment: You should use the original. What's giving you the "exception"? You might want to use double quotes for `value`

Comment: That should work. Where are you getting this exception?

Comment: Thanks. The exception come from the jspx, not from any java code,  `/WEB-INF/views/order/detail.jspx (line: 164, column: 23) Element type "size" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"`

Comment: What does the entire file look like? Can you provide some more context?

Comment: Is the javascript inside a <script> tag?

Comment: Just update the post with code layout. Thanks everyone. Please share your opinions.

Comment: Do you use `CDATA` in your script? You should. jspx expects well formed xml and maybe the parser has problems with that code. That said I recommend using good old jsp.

Comment: @zeroflagL Could you please give me an example? I thought EL can take precedence so not necessary for CDATA

Comment: @Dreamer `<c:out />` is not EL ;) Try inserting `// <![CDATA[` as first line and `// ]]>` as last line into your `script` tag. It's just a guess but worth a try.

Comment: @Dreamer I just realized that `<c:out/>` would probably be ignored then.

Comment: @Dreamer But a pure EL expression (without `<c:out/>` might still work then.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [the answer of the link of the post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3287264/1065197), it would be better if you first define a variable with your needs and then use the value of that variable in JavaScript:

```
<c:set var="ordersLength" value="${fn:length(orders)}"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var size= "<c:out value='${ordersLength}'/>";
</script>
```

Another option would be setting the value of `${fn:length(orders)}` in a hidden field and read this field value in JavaScript:

```
<input type="hidden" id="ordersLength" value="${fn:length(orders)}" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    var size = document.getElementById('ordersLength').value;
</script>
```

Of course, this last option is clumsy but might help you to solve this issue.

If none of these work it means your `orders` variable isn't set nor as request attribute nor as session attribute nor as application attribute nor as page attribute (and by the provided code in your answer, we aren't capable to help you with that [yet]).

Answer (score 0):

You can't get it to work with jspx files. You can with jsp files.

jspx files require well formed XML. The XML is validated before the EL is processed, and so your code fails.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9359209/conditional-html-attribute-in-jspx) for better a explination